# How should we abbreviate this tag "Kiss: Psycho Circus: The Nightmare Child"?

Tags: discussion, tags

"Kiss: Psycho Circus: The Nightmare Child" is clearly over 25 characters, so how should we abbreviate this tag? I made the tag [kiss-psycho-circus-tnc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiss-psycho-circus-tnc) just so we would have something to put for it on the question that just was asked about it, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to abbreviate it. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This tag was renamed to [kiss-psycho-circus-nightmare-child](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiss-psycho-circus-nightmare-child).**

Following the maximum tag length being [increased to 35](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12497/181240), this tag was renamed by Robotnik on August 16<sup>th</sup>, 2017. The old tag [kiss-psycho-circus-tnc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiss-psycho-circus-tnc) was made into a synonymn.

[image: Tag rename]

Answer (score 10):

After some brief research, the game appears to be based off of the comic book series [Kiss: Psycho Circus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiss:_Psycho_Circus). Since that title is the overarching series, it'd be the most easily identifiable part of the game's title. As such, I think the tag you've created works just fine.