# What tag should be used for "Plants vs Zombies: Garden Warfare"

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, there isn't a tag for Plants Vs. Zombies: Garden Warfare. This means that questions like [Plants vs. Zombies: Garden Warfare Multiplayer on Xbox One & PS4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/249138/181240) are tagged with [plants-vs-zombies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plants-vs-zombies).

Ideally, questions like this would be retagged with [plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare), but that's well past the 25 character limit allowed for tags.

What tag should be used for questions about Plants Vs Zombies: Garden Warfare?

---

***Update:*** Turns out there already was a tag for PVZ:GW. [plants-vs-zombies-gw](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plants-vs-zombies-gw) has been added as a synonym for the existing tag [pvz-garden-warfare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pvz-garden-warfare).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the recent tag length increase, the tag is now [plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare), with [pvz-gw](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pvz-gw) as a synonym.

---

<strike>[pvz-garden-warfare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pvz-garden-warfare) exists already and should be used for questions about Plants vs Zombies: Garden Warfare.</strike>

I assume this name was chosen as 'PvZ' is a common abbreviation of *Plants vs Zombies*.

Comment: Would it be possible to either rename the tag or add [plants-vs-zombies-gw] as a synonym?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro - I've added [plants-vs-zombies-gw] as a synonym of the already existing tag as that's the lightest touch - if there is enough support to reverse the synonym direction we can action that at a later date.

Comment: @Robotnik i didn't even notice there was an existing tag. good catch

Answer (score 1):

I would propose the tag [plants-vs-zombies-gw](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plants-vs-zombies-gw), as it fits with our general tagging convention for really long tags. See [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12370/how-should-we-abbreviate-this-tag-kiss-psycho-circus-the-nightmare-child) for one example. Generally speaking, if the entire name fits, use it; but if it doesn't, spell out the most easily identifiable part of the tag and abbreviate the modifier in a way that makes sense. Then write a good tag wiki and usage guidance so people can what the tag is for if they are at all uncertain.

Comment: Is it bad my first thought on seeing that tag was "Plants vs Zombies Gone Wild"? All joking aside, that tag name does make sense.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro idk. but if there ever becomes a game named that, we may have to consider changing our tagging conventions or ask for longer tags.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro ...I just read it that way and can't see it as garden warfare now. Dammit.